# Mock a method call from an object created inside a function (python)

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

```py
class Foo:
       def do_work:
          client = Client()
          client.widgets(self.widget_id).parts().get()``
```

I have the above code. Client() class is defined in another package.
I am trying to unit test it with mock as follows:

```py
    magic_mock = MagicMock()
    api_client = Client()
    magic_mock.api_client.widgets().parts().get.return_value = self.generate_mock
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. What is a better approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your class is in `mymodule.py`:

```
# mymodule.py
from othermodule import Client

class Foo:
    def do_work():
        client = Client()
        return client.widgets(self.widget_id).parts().get()
```

Then your test module should be something like (implement that generate_mock instead of `mocked_value`):

```
# test_mymodule.py
from unittest.mock import patch

import mymodule


@patch('mymodule.Client')
def test_client_widgets_parts_get_returned(mocked):
    mocked_value = "foo"
    mocked.return_value.widgets.return_value.parts.return_value.get.return_value = mocked_value
    returned = mymodule.Foo().do_work()
    assert returned == mocked_value
```

Or without changing your `do_work`:

```
@patch('mymodule.Client')
def test_client_widgets_parts_get_called(mocked):
    mymodule.Foo().do_work()
    mocked.return_value.widgets.return_value.parts.return_value.get.assert_called()
```

P.S. stacked decorators are added from the bottom:

```
@patch('mymodule.Other')
@patch('mymodule.Client')
def test_client_widgets_parts_get_called(mocked_client, mocked_other):
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. However, it turns out, I have another external object inside mymodule.Foo().do_work() that needs patched. What is the proper syntax for that?